# how to compare partial text is present or not on HTML popup in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, compare

I need to check some partial text is present or not on HTML popup,because some text is dynamic.

My Scenario is like this:

- Enter username and password and click on login button.
- system showing alert message as : The password is,Expires on dd/mm/yy (expiry date is dynamic) Before this date, Reset the password

I just want to check if 'The password is' text is present or not.
There are other HTML popups has the same `div` `ID` and `class`, only the alert message text is different.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="msgBox1481602403457" class="msgBox" style="opacity: 1; top: 19.5px; left: 566.5px; background-image: url("styles/images/msgBoxBackGround.png");">  
<div class="msgBoxTitle">Information</div>
  <div>
     <div class="msgBoxContainer">
     <div id="msgBox1481602403457Image" class="msgBoxImage">
     <img src="styles/images/info.png">
 </div>

<div id="msgBox1481602403457Content" class="msgBoxContent">
  <p>
    <span>
       The Password is,
       <br>
       Expires on dd/mm/yy
       <br>
       Before this date,
       <br>
        Reset the password
    </span>
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="msgBox1481602403457Buttons" class="msgBoxButtons">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what have you done so far? post that code

Comment: I tried below ways

    String text = "The password is";
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + text + "')]"));
    
     if (text.equals(list))
     {
      System.out.println("Please reset your password,It will be     expired");
     }
     else
     {
      System.out.println("Go ahead");
     }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way -

```
String divText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("@class='msgBoxContent'")).getText();
```

The above line of code should give you the full text in that div - *The Password is, Expires on dd/mm/yy Before this date, Reset the password*

Then use the contains() method to check if the text you are looking for is available.

```
if(divText.contains("The Password is")) {
    System.out.println("match found");
} else {
    System.out.println("match not found");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, its working for me.
I just updated xpath as: 

    String divText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='msgBoxContent']/p/span")).getText();